# Changing Chinese Font Size

Tags: xetex, fontsize, xecjk

I've tried to set the default font size through the `documentclass` optional parameter but the font size hasn't changed. I'm using `xetex` with `texmaker`.

My document:

```
\documentclass[60pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,hhline}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[16pt]{SimSun}

\begin{document}
\section*{前言}
...
```

Absolute beginner in Latex - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the ctexart class.
For the font size, try such as
`\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1.6]{SimSun}`.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto When I do that the 8 characters span the width of an A4 page, which is the case whether `[Scale=1.6]` or  `[Scale=0.3]`. Originally about 45 Chinese characters span a page, which I would like to change it to about 30.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify the font size like that as an option for `setCJKmainfont`. That's what I tried to do as well at first, but then I found this somewhere:

```
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1.5]{SimSun}
```

This uses the main font size (`\setmainfont[Scale=...]{font name}`) and multiplies its size to get a value for the size of the CJK font.

**EDIT:**

Note that maybe document classes don't support all font sizes. This might be the reason why the font size didn't change, when you changed that option. In such a case it defaults, usually to 10pt or 11pt, depending on the document class' settings / code.

Comment: Does this change the font for headings too?